# WPF Window not having title named correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that has the title set to "Pioneer Document Handling Viewer" within the xaml:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:mt="clr-namespace:DocumentHandlingTouch" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="DocumentHandlingTouch.MainWindow"
Title="Pioneer Document Handling Viewer" Height="909" Width="1020" WindowState="Maximized"
   Icon="default_document.ico" xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
```

But it shows up with an older title:[image: Title From running window] when I run it. 
I've tried a clean rebuild. Reopening the project, etc and the title still doesn't change.
Why would the XAML be different than the runtime title?

Comment: i think i had an issue with this once, try setting it in the code behind after (maybe before?) `InitializeComponent()` with `this.Title = ""`

Comment: `Window` xaml gets compiled into [baml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Application_Markup_Language) during project compiling. Maybe there is something preventing re-compling and you have old baml.

Comment: @rigamonk are you sure you don't set it in code behind. Search for the title you see at run time in your solution